# Why doesn't this custom QWidget display correctly

Tags: python-3.x, background, pyqt5, qwidget, qtstylesheets

I'm retrying this question with a much better code example.

The code below, in its current form, will display a green shaded `QWidget` in a window, which is what I want.  However, when commenting out the line:

```
self.widget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
```

and uncommenting,

```
self.widget = Widget_1(self.centralwidget)
```

the green box doesn't display.  The `Widget_1` class is a simple subclass of `QWidget`, so I'm trying to wrap my head around where the breakdown is occurring.  There are no error messages, and the `print("Test")` line within the `Widget_1` class is outputting just fine, so I know everything is being called properly.

I'm not looking to use any type of automated layouts for reasons I don't need to go into here.  Can you help me to understand why the green rectangle isn't displaying, and what correction I would need to make in order to utilize the `Widget_1` class?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect
import sys

class Main_Window(object):
    def setupUi(self, seating_main_window):
        seating_main_window.setObjectName("seating_main_window")
        seating_main_window.setEnabled(True)
        seating_main_window.resize(400, 400)

        self.centralwidget = QWidget(seating_main_window)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        ###########  The following two lines of code are causing the confusion  #######

        #  The following line, when uncommented, creates a shaded green box in a window
        self.widget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)  # Working line

        #  The next line does NOT create the same shaded green box.  Where is it breaking?
        # self.widget = Widget_1(self.centralwidget) # Non-working line

        self.widget.setGeometry(QRect(15, 150, 60, 75))
        self.widget.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background: rgb(170, 255, 0)")
        self.widget.setObjectName("Widget1")

        seating_main_window.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

class Widget_1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(10, 30)  # I put this in thinking maybe I just couldn't see it
        print("Test")   # I see this output when run when Widget_1 is used above

class DemoApp(QMainWindow, Main_Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':  # if we're running file directly and not importing it
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)  # A new instance of QApplication
    form = DemoApp()  # We set the form to be our ExampleApp (design)
    form.show()  # Show the form
    app.exec_()  # run the main function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoriding to this Qt Wiki article:

- [How to Change the Background Color of QWidget](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Change_the_Background_Color_of_QWidget)

you must implement `paintEvent` in a custom `QWidget` subclass in order to use stylesheets. Also, since the widget is not part of a layout, you must give it a parent, otherwise it will not be shown. So your `Widget_1` class must look like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyleOption, QStyle
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter

class Widget_1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent) # set the parent
        print("Test")

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        option = QStyleOption()
        option.initFrom(self)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_Widget, option, painter, self)
        super().paintEvent(event)
```

Comment: I would have never caught that.  Thank you!